# Postition of typeahead ngx-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, typehead

I have `typeahead` from `ngx-bootstrap`, and I want to locate it so that typeahead dropdown is in the centre of my input.

I mean something like this https://joxi.ru/82383oJCJ4gGyA

[Link to StackBliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t7zk2g)

Thanks!

Comment: what's your mean about **typeahead dropdown is in the centre of my input.**

Comment: I mean something like this http://joxi.ru/82383oJCJ4gGyA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks no way to change [position setting](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/392279d720cd52bbb316b34366fff21b9f00c9c8/src/typeahead/typeahead.ts#L176) in ng-bootstrap

So I use CSS to overwrite it, but it needs to be careful to use it to avoid having too much `!important` syntax

[Link to StackBliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdhigy?file=src/app/app.component.css)

**app.component.css**

```
// :host => only work in app.component.css
// :host ::ng-deep => look for selector `typeahead-container.dropdown-menu` in `app.component.css`
:host ::ng-deep typeahead-container.dropdown-menu {
    left: 50%!important;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

/*
// it will be compiled to this
[_nghost-c0] typeahead-container.dropdown-menu {
    left: 50%!important;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
*/
```